# How to run cable from attic to breaker panel in a finished room

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, circuit

I want to install a new circuit breaker and run 10/3 NM cable from attic and into the breaker panel. The panel is in a finished bedroom.  How would I fish the cable to the panel considering potential insulation and running into other wires? Ideally, I don't want to remove the drywall above the panel.

Comment: I mean the only way possible without removing the drywall is if you have an open tab on top (or direction you are going) and you can start from the box and go in that direction.   I have done similar things and only removed a small bit of drywall.  No matter what you will need pictures of panel and where you are going and what's in between (diagram).

Comment: Place a framed cabinet door (with a latch) on the wall above the panel.  Open door. Hollow out drywall.  Vacuum up bits.  Add cabling.  Use for stash.

Comment: The secret to  lot of electrical work is that drywall repair is just a fact of life, unless you or a previous worker has provisioned plenty of conduit going where you want things to go. Which would certainly be the smart move with a panel in a finished space, but is rarely seen (we put in every electrical doo-dad anyone could ever want - no need for future expansion here! Famous Last Words...)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is an INTERIOR un-insulated wall and that you have an unused knock-out in the top of the breaker panel. Also ONLY do this with ALL power to the panel turned off, including the incoming line, so don't plan on doing this at night. In some cases (such as the Main Disconnect being IN this panel) that might require you to have the Power Company kill the power by pulling the meter.Also if this is an insulated wall, it's not likely something you can do yourself.

One (poor man's) way to do it is to find the top plate (usually a sideways 2x4) in the attic directly above your panel, often you can see any other wires that are going into the attic (if any) coming through it. Drill a 1" hole down into the wall space through that top plate. Punch out the knock-out in the panel and place a flashlight shining up that hole toward the top plate. From the ceiling, look down through your hole and see how close you are to being DIRECTLY over it. If not, drill a new hole closer. Then tie a strong string to a fishing weight that is small enough to go through both holes, tie it to a nail in the attic and lower it down through the top plate hole until it goes through the knock-out opening. Then using that string, tie it onto a looped wire at the end of the NM cable and use it to pull the cable back up from the panel to the attic. Don't forget to put a cable clamp in the box before terminating the wire onto the breaker.

There are more specific tools that professional electricians would use, but they are expensive for a one-off DIY project.

Comment: Unfortunately most panels are on exterior insulated walls. Cable clamp do you have a type in mind? There are a few non metallic snap in styles. Having room for a 1” hole above a panel is optimistic that it would be directly above a knockout so that makes a 30$ fish rod well worth the cost.

Answer (score 3):

If the wall is an external wall this is really tough.
 I have used fish rods (thin fiberglass rods pushed through the panel.
  One advantage today that make it possible are clamps like raco insiders these Romex clamps can be put in after the wire is pulled from the inside of the box. 
(Many home owners just left the cable in the opening without a clamp). In 2 cases I have been called to repair when the hot shorted out on the sharp edge of the panel that is not a lot but one required a new panel and a lot of wiring to repair burnt wires, the other just re-pulling the burnt wire.

I have found putting a pull string on the leading edge of the fish rod and going up until I find the hole in the top plate works best.
 Remove the string pull the rod out through the bottom , tie the string to the Romex and pull the cable down to the panel. 
2 people make this much easier For me I would almost rather repair a small section of drywall and have to paint than fight getting a fish rod through the panel and then the top plate by myself.  the “insiders”  plastic clamp makes this possible but still a chore. I usually put a hard plastic shield over the lugs if the panel is a main lug style and am very cautious when trying to find the hole above not to come in contact with any hot wires. hope this helps.

Comment: Totally agree with this and starting to itch just thinking about all the times I did this with fiberglass insulation, in the dark with a flashlight.+